# Manjaro equivalent for the Arch Linux Archive repository?

Tags: manjaro

Is there a Manjaro equivalent for the [Arch Linux Archive](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Arch_Linux_Archive)? It allows me to upgrade (or roll back) to the state of packages on a particular day. This is needed when some software (eg Pytorch stack) isn't ready to work with a brand new version of Python or CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new service at manjaro.tuxboy.eu.
online about 2/3 weeks ago. You can find old packages there or use ( if you use manjaro ) manjaro-downgrade package from testing repository. In this repository you find only the packages build from Manjaro team others are always in ALA.

Cheers
Stefano

Comment: Hi Stefano, is there more information on manjaro.tuxboy.eu? (Or any other Manjaro archive mirror?) I checked it out and it seems promising as an archive mirror. I would really like the option to stick Manjaro to a specific version if needed like Arch does.

Comment: Hi, at the moment this service keep only the last ten pkgs specific for Manjaro to integrate with Arch.